# Auto generation of a sequence number in c# or SQL

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a situation where user enters a number of length 9 digits. But some people will only enter three digits like 901. So when they enter three digits in the text box, i have to auto generate the rest of the 6 digits and insert it into the database. I should check this against data base table that what was the last auto generated number with 901 and insert next value to it. 
I just need a suggestion not the complete solution, that i should do this c# or SQL. Which is the best way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why do the users enter the number? Normally the database would return the next number. What if 000000901,000000902 and 000000903 already exist and the user enters 901, should 000000904 be returned?

Comment: Users means in my company data entry guys...if a person on our site don't have reference number given, then our data entry guys enter 901 to auto generate a number for them.And our number should start with 901 and rest of the 6 numbers should be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. As Tim mentioned, seems the system should provide the user with the number, not the user providing the system with the number. At any rate you'll want to use a database which would at the least contain a series of primary keys [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key] (numbers not to be duplicated). Se the key to auto increment. This will ensure no other user has the same number/id.